# Why is $\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}T^nX)=1$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be an $T$-invariant measure on $(X,\mathcal{B})$. Then it is
$$
\mu(T^nX)=\mu(T^{-n}T^nX)=\mu(X)=1.
$$

Why is then
$$
\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}T^n(X))=1?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $n$ you have $\mu(X \setminus T^nX)=0$, so
$$\mu \left( \bigcup_n (X \setminus T^nX) \right) \le \sum_n\mu (X \setminus T^nX) = \sum_n 0 = 0$$
But now, 
$$0=\mu\left( \bigcup_n (X \setminus T^nX) \right) = \mu \left(X \setminus \left( \bigcap_n T^nX \right) \right) = 1- \mu\left( \bigcap_n T^nX \right)$$

Comment: From what do you know that $\mu(\bigcap_n T^nX)<\infty$ in order that you can do the last step?

Comment: Isn't $\mu$ a finite measure? You have $\mu(X)=1$, as you wrote.

Comment: Oh, right, it's supposed to be a probability measure.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposition:** Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)=1$. If $\{E_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{B}$ such that $\mu(E_n)=1$ for all $n$, then $\mu(\bigcap_n E_n) = 1$.

**Proof:** Note that $\mu(E_n^c) = 1-\mu(E_n)=1-1=0$ for all $n$, so it follows that $\mu(\bigcup_nE_n^c) \leq \sum_n \mu(E_n^c) = 0$, and thus $\mu(\bigcap_n E_n) = 1 - \mu(\bigcup_n E_n^c) = 1-0=1$. $\Box$

Now apply the proposition with $E_n = T^n(X)$.

Comment: Whoops... too late.